# Meta Tag Grabber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, meta-tags

I was wondering if anyone knows of any good code/applications/Gems to grab meta data (title & description) from any website?

I have a recipe site and users can add the URL of where they got the recipe from, I want to auto generate a title and description of the site from this URL submitted.

Any ideas/ thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) is a simple html parser, since you just want the meta tag information that should be simple enough.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.example.com'))
doc.xpath('//meta').each do |meta|
  puts meta.name
  puts meta.content
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do I just need to include the Gem and the above code? Is there a way to put this out in the view with embedded ruby?

Comment: yep, the gem is nokogiri, and you'd just put it in the view like normal, this would live in the controller.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure what the down vote was for whoever it was. Will accept answer cheers

Comment: Wasn't me but people often don't like questions about looking for gems e.t.c. (often opinion based, little research). If you do post one, make sure to include how you've looked for them before posting the question or what gems you've found.